# GtkWidget -> GtkToolItem function? Adding a GtkWidget to a GtkToolItemGroup

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I was looking at GtkToolPalette, it looks great. But I was wondering at the possibility to add a GtkHScale to one of the groups of the palette. I've checked GtkToolItemGroup can add only items of type GtkToolItem; Is there a way to get a GtkToolItem for an existing GtkWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

> GtkToolItems are widgets that can appear on a toolbar. To create a toolbar item that contain something else than a button, use gtk_tool_item_new(). Use gtk_container_add() to add a child widget to the tool item.

from [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkToolItem.html#GtkToolItem.description)

Comment: Great, thank you.. I definitely didn't do well the homework of reading the API docs.